# Include crashlytics in library

Tags: android, crashlytics

I would like to know if it is possible to monitor exceptions with Crashlytics in a library project.

I'm the developer of the library, I do not own the parent app.
I also don't care about exceptions in the parent app, I only want the exceptions caused by my library.
I'm afraid that I already know the answer, but maybe it is possible in some way.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It's a good question!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is not possible at this moment.
I contacted the guys from Crashlytics and they confirmed this, but there are plans to support it in the future.

Many thanks to the Crashlytics team for their quick support ;)

Comment: You should be able to provide/encourage the app module to use your crashlytics api key, such as the one you generated in your test app for your library. As far as I know you can share that key to cumulatively collect reports but of course it's not plausible to enforce this approach and it's far from being practical at all.